# how to pass exchange data between components in Angular2

Tags: angular2-template

M new to angular2 and m trying  to learn a simple thing that how to exchange data between two components , I got there is a way of exchanging data between  parent and child component but what i am trying is in my Appcomponent i am routing it to different component so how do i pass data .

What i am trying to do:
In my app component m selecting a value from a dropdown  and m trying to access next component like this in my appcomponent.html

```
<li role="presentation"><a class="onmousehover" routerLink="recycle"><b>Recycle</b></a></li>
```

and in my appRoute.ts i have routed it to recycle component like this

```
export const appRoutes:Routes=[
{path:'leftpane', component:LeftPaneComponent,children:leftpane_routes},
{path:'recycle',component:RecycleComponent}
];
```

So can any one help me to figure it out how the value from appcomponet i pass it to recycle component

Answer (score 0):

You can use services and rxjs Observables.
You create a service in app component and inject that service in child components using DI. that service can have BehaviorSubjects with shared data which your child component can subscribe.
Another way would be resolvers + services so you resolve data for a route before the route is loaded.
And the third method can be ngrx it's basically a service which is global on your app. but it implements the redux pattern.